# MySQL Daemon Failed to Start - centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

So not sure why I am getting such error.

When I type: mysql

I get:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I know that there should be a mysql.sock file in that directory, so I create one. But the file just auto removes its self and I continue to get the error 2002.

I am also unable to log into PHPMyAdmin due to the error. I can access phpmyadmin page but when logging in I get: `#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server`

EDIT:

Here is my mysql.log file:

```
131201 13:05:07 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
131201 13:18:18 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
131201 13:18:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
131201 13:18:18 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
131201 13:18:18 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131201 13:18:18 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131201 13:18:18 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
131201 13:18:18 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
131201 13:18:18 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131201 13:18:18 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131201 13:18:18  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
131201 13:18:18 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I ran mysql_upgrade and got

```
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Comment: It is not the error message of the mysqld, it is only the symptom that it didn't start. There is a server log, probably in /var/log, where you can see, what happened. Check this please and edit this into your question.

Comment: @PeterHorvath I have added it.

Comment: Thanks. It seems your mysqld hasn't permission to /var/lib/mysql. The simplest way to test it, if you "su" to the mysql user (as root: su mysql -s /bin/bash ), go into this directory and try to make something (f.e. mkdir test; rmdir test). Try this, what happens?